# How to update select query with group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I update the row `total_talktime` on `mobile_users` table with the SUM of this following query with the correct`user_id`? using group by?

This is the Select query:

```
SELECT SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( `calls`.`finished_call` , `calls`.`start_call` ) ) ) AS `t` , `mobile_users`.`id`
FROM `mobile_users` 
LEFT JOIN `calls` ON `calls`.`user_id` = `mobile_users`.`id`
GROUP BY `mobile_users`.`id`
```

How could I make it work with Update Select, incl group by?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your query is working
try this

```
update table   
set total_talktime = (select t from  
(SELECT SUM (TIME_TO_SEC (TIMEDIFF ( `calls`.`finished_call` , `calls`.`start_call`  ) ) ) AS `t`, `mobile_users`.`id`
FROM `mobile_users` 
LEFT JOIN `calls` ON `calls`.`user_id` = `musers`.`id`
GROUP BY `mobile_users`.`id` ) as subquery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`UPDATE mobile_users SET total_talktime = (SELECT SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( calls.finished_call , calls.start_call ) ) ) AS t , mobile_users.id
FROM mobile_users 
LEFT JOIN calls ON calls.user_id = musers.id
GROUP BY mobile_users.id )`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the query but hope this helps:

```
update table
set total_talktime  = derived.t
from table, 
(
SELECT SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( `calls`.`finished_call` , `calls`.`start_call` ) ) ) AS `t` , `mobile_users`.`id`
FROM `mobile_users` 
LEFT JOIN `calls` ON `calls`.`user_id` = `mobile_users`.`id`
GROUP BY `mobile_users`.`id` 
) derived
where table.userId = derived.id
```